# Indicators and icons not appearing in WingPanel

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel

I'm having a weird problem with WingPanel. The network indicator isn't present at all and used to be, and I'm not seeing my other tray items as I should be.

[image]

I should be seeing the network dropdown and Skype, Syncthing, Dropbox, etc., but I see nothing. I'm on a pretty fresh install of Freya, and I'm up to date on all packages as of right now.

Comment: what is output of `sudo apt-get install indicator-application xdg-user-dirs xdg-user-dirs-gtk`

Comment: I think that somehow `indicator-application` was uninstalled and it now seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a possible solution, I am not sure whether it is exact solution or not*

(please comment if you want to downvote).

The possible reason for Indicators and icons missing in WIngPanel is:

sometimes dependencies are getting removed: (most of the cases these are the *culprits* )

indicator-application
xdg-user-dirs
xdg-user-dirs-gtk

Open terminal and run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-application xdg-user-dirs xdg-user-dirs-gtk
```

Comment: Unable to confirm because it's now working, but I think this would fix it.