# Missing volume icon

Tags: wingpanel, indicator-sound

Since a couple of days ago my volume icon has disappeared from Wingpanel. 
I know this issue has surfaced before, but the go-to solution (install `indicator-sound`) is of no use (`indicator-sound` correctly installed).

As an addition, this issue is not user-related, since it affects me even if I log into a guest session.

Any help to troubleshoot this?

**As per requested edit:**

```
apt-cache policy indicator-sound
indicator-sound:
  Installed: 12.10.2+14.04.20140401-0ubuntu1+elementary4~ubuntu0.3.1
  Candidate: 12.10.2+14.04.20140401-0ubuntu1+elementary4~ubuntu0.3.1
  Version table:
 *** 12.10.2+14.04.20140401-0ubuntu1+elementary4~ubuntu0.3.1 0
        999 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     12.10.2+14.04.20140401-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

**Update Dec.10:** Just to let you know that the issue is still there. Despite Ravan's workarounds, the solution appears to work intermittently, meaning that every other reboot or so the volume icon doesn't show up. It's worth noticing that the service is active, though, because I can modify the volume via keyboard shortcuts. My feeling is that there's something wrong in Wingpanel and the way indicators are displayed or not.

Comment: Have you tried reinstall `indicator-sound` ?

Comment: Hello, @Giulio any update? Please have a look at the answer and let me know https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2646/indicators-and-icons-not-appearing-in-wingpanel?rq=1

Comment: Nope, still not working. I have all the necessary packages correctly installed.

Comment: As I was saying in my comment below, it must be an autostart issue.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: the service - if that's the correct term - just doesn't start automatically. In fact, after clicking on the destop file you mentioned the icon is correctly displayed.

Comment: that means you have volume icon, but it disappear after reboot?

Comment: Yeah. Or, if you prefer, I have no icon at boot unless I manually launch sound indicator :)

Comment: Please drop [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32269/ravan-and-giulio-sant) to avoid discussion in comments :)

Answer (score 3):

The following are possible solutions:

- Reinstall `indicator-sound`

  Open terminal and run:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-sound
  ```
- Install `dconf`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
  ```

  Now open dconf:

  com --> canonical --> indicator--> sound --> **visible**

  [image: Imgur]

---

If still not working:

Also make sure 
the `/etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-sound.desktop` file should be exactly like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Indicator Sound
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
OnlyShowIn=Unity;XFCE;GNOME;Pantheon;
NoDisplay=true
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
AutostartCondition=GNOME3 unless-session gnome
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=indicator-sound
```

*Note*: log out and log in

---

The problem is temporarily solved (see [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32269/ravan-and-giulio-sant)) after modifying `/usr/share/upstart/xdg/autostart/indicator-sound.desktop` and adding `Pantheon` to `OnlyShowIn`, like:

```
OnlyShowIn=Unity;XFCE;Pantheon;
```

There will be three auto start options used by indicators

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-sound.desktop
/usr/share/upstart/xdg/autostart/indicator-sound.desktop
/usr/share/upstart/sessions/indicator-sound.conf
```

1st is from freedesktop std, should be started by session
2nd startup app lauched by upstart
3rd upstart (session mode) deprecated i think and replace by 2nd file
so in this case 1st is not working
hard to say as I never traced similar thing

Reference [Sneetsher post in AU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473784/battery-indicator-has-disappeared-from-gnome-panel/482152#482152)

Comment: Everything looks fine on my part. Running the desktop file, though, made the icon appear on the panel. Looks like a matter of autostart after all.

Comment: I have just edited my post, please have a look :)

Comment: If still anything not working, edit your post and add output of `apt-cache policy indicator-sound`

Comment: Had the same problem. (Re-)Installing `indicator-sound` worked for me.

Comment: Nothing works so far. Still no icon at boot.